# How to get term link that crosses different custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, terms

In my WordPress project, I have several different `custom post types` and they all share a **common** taxonomy. I am in the final stage of the project and now is time to link all custom post types using a sidebar widget. The problem I am having is that I don't know the appropriate way to get the `term link` linked to the correct custom post type.

For example, I have custom post types: book, author, product; and a taxonomy: genre that includes a horror category.

I would like to be able to get link structure as such:

```
/book/genre/horror
/product/genre/horror
/author/genre/horror
```

When I do `get_term_link('horror');`, I get one of the term links, it seems that one of the custom post type has preference. How can I manage to get each term link corresponding to the correct custom post type?

Hard coding it is never a good idea, so I was wondering if there is a proper way to go about this. This is an old issue I am having, and have done a lot of searching for a solution but I didn't find it. I come here as the last resort. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think that `get_term_link()` should return a URL based on post types on a shared taxonomy? It has not sense for me. The term link should be `/genre/horror` where all post types of `horror` term are listed. Then you can build a filtering system to filter the results based on post types and use the rewrite API and term_link filter if you want to have pretty permalinks for that filtered results. It would be different if the taxonomy wouldn't sahred across multiple post types.

Comment: I know `get_term_link()` wouldn't work. I was hoping for something in the lines of `get_term_link('horror', array( 'post_type'=>'movie'));` and I don't think that is too much to ask for. I will look into the rewrite API, I never understood it very well, usually I use a plugin to do that dirty work for me but I guess now is time.

Answer (score 1):

This code display all posts of all categories of **genre taxonomy** for **custom post type book**.  Now, For different **custom post type (author, product ) you have to change Custom Post Type Name inside $arg of WP_Query().** You will get term link using  get_term_link($catterm) function or you can use also [get_the_term_list()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list).

```
 $args = array(
            'number'     => $number,
            'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
            'include'    => $ids
        );

        $custom_categories = get_terms( 'genre ', $args );

        foreach ( $custom_categories as $catterm){

            $arg = Array( 
            'post_type' => 'book',
            'posts_per_page' => '-1',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'tax_query' => Array( Array ( 
            'taxonomy' => 'genre ' ,
            'terms' => $catterm->term_id
            )) );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $arg ); 
        global $post;
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        ?>

        <div class="gallery-content">
        <div class="entry-content">

        <?php 
         echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
         echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($catterm).'">'.$catterm->name.'</a></li>';   
        ?>  

        </div>
        </div>

       <?php endwhile;
        }   
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I figured out a way to accomplish this. Here is my solution.

Taking my example above, I will walk you through what I did to get `example.com/book/genre/horror` to point to custom post type `book`, taxonomy `genre` and category `horror`.

Pretty permalinks should be enabled. Go to Settings > Permalinks to enable it. Otherwise there is no point of doing this. So here we go...

1) Create a page called book (and slug book), note the page ID that was generated for that page after you have published it, you will need it ( you can see this in your URL, should be a `?post=` with the page ID in it.)

2) Now we need to create a rewrite so that we can point the link to the correct template page. So, in your `functions.php` file (or your plugin file, up to you) you need to add this code:

```
function my_rewrite_rules() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        'book/genre/([[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)?/?$',
        'index.php?page_id=1234&genre=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrite_rules' );
```

Now, replace 1234 with the page ID you generated for the page `book`. And go to any front end page and reload it.

**Important:** you don't want to run `flush_rewrite_rules();` every time a page is loaded in your site. This is a heavy function and will slow things down for you. You only need to run it once on the **front end**. After you reloaded any page on the front end, the rewrite rules are flushed and you can remove this line.

What this function does is, if a url is has the structure of `/book/genre/ANYTHING_HERE/`, WordPress will redirect user to the page with ID of 1234 with the data `genre=ANYTHING_HERE`. Note that ANYTHING_HERE is filtered through the regular expression provided, and that will only accept characters (upper-case and lower-case) from a-z, numbers 0-9 and dash (-).

3) Go to your theme folder and create a file called `page-1234.php` (replacing 1234 with **your** page ID, of course.) Now in this file you can do all sorts of fun stuff. Here is how you could list all books **by genre**:

```
<?php
get_header(); 

global $wp_query;
$genre = $wp_query->query_vars['genre'];

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'genre',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $genre,
        ), ),
);

$books = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<h1>Books of <?php echo $genre;?></h1>
<ul>
<?php foreach ( $books as $book ) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $book->post_title; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In addition, if you are not working with taxonomies, like `genre` in this example, you could use your custom tags. By the way, the term `genre` only works in this example because it was registered as a taxonomy. If this wasn't the case, you could add a new tag to WordPress, whatever you would like, by adding this to your `functions.php` as such:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%food%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

Now you replace `genre` in the step 2 with the tag `food`. In your `page-1234.php` you can get the `query_vars['food']` and manipulate it any way you like and run requests like `example.com/book/food/chocolate`. Note that some query_vars are reserved. Check the resources below for them.

To finish off, to get the links to point to the correct custom post type and taxonomy, you need a custom function. This is the only way I could think of doing this and it is something like this:

```
function get_books_category_link( $category_slug ) {

    $page = get_permalink( 1234 );
    $link = '';

    if ( '/%postname%/' == get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
        $link = $page . 'genre/' . $category_slug;
    } else {
        $link = add_query_arg( array( 'genre' => $category_slug ) , $page );
    }

    return $link;
}
```

And that's it! Hope it helps. Some great reads below, specially the article from Stephen Harris really made a difference on understanding the rewrite API. Thanks.

[Tuts+ The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474)

[Rewrite API/add rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

[WordPress Query Vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Query_Vars)